# Dynamic table storage name

Tags: azure-table-storage, azure-data-factory, azure-management-api

is it possible to have a dynamic table storage table name in a data factory input?

Everything what I find is with a fix name

```
"properties": {
 "type": "AzureTable",
 "linkedServiceName": "StorageLinkedService",
 "typeProperties": {
     "tableName": "MyTable"
 },
```

The situation is that I want to copy the data of a dynamic list of tables into a sql database.

Answer (score 1):

You can parameterize the table name in Azure Data Factory v2 for an Azure Table Storage dataset.

I created this manually in the authoring tool, but the corresponding (exported) arm template looks like this:

```
"parameters": {
    "table": {
        "type": "string"
    }
},
"annotations": [],
"type": "AzureTable",
"schema": [],
"typeProperties": {
    "tableName": {
        "value": "@dataset().table",
        "type": "Expression"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe you will have to create separate Datasets with static table names. Dynamic table names are not possible!!

Answer (score 0):

Sadly not!

I've just tested this is I was hoping that you'd be able to inject values from the partition by clause. However, this is only possible in file and folder names it seems. **Not for tables**.

See below screen shot.

Not allowed according to the portal, even though it deploys without failing validation!!

I've just created a MS connect feedback item for it, link below.

https://feedback.azure.com/forums/270578-data-factory/suggestions/18614509-support-the-partition-by-clause-for-azure-table-da

Go vote for it to be added to ADF functionality.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you use .NET API then you can achieve it.

using `Microsoft.Azure.Management.DataFactories` nuget package

```
var dataFactoryClient = new DataFactoryClient {
    ResourceGroupName = "",
    DataFactoryName = ""
}

var client = dataFactoryClient.GetDataFactoryManagementClient();

client.Datasets.CreateOrUpdate(ResourceGroupName, DataFactoryName,
                new DatasetCreateOrUpdateParameters
                {
                    Dataset = new Dataset
                    {
                        Name = datasetName,
                        Properties = new DatasetProperties
                        {
                            LinkedServiceName = linkedService,
                            TypeProperties = new AzureTableDataset
                            {
                                TableName = tableName //append current date

                            },
                            External = external,
                            Availability = availability,
                            Structure = //DataElements
                            Policy = new Policy {}

                        }
                    }
                });
```

You can also access pipelines, activities, linkedservices using this API and customize them as per the need.

You can use WebJob to deploy this DataFactory.